# Create nDimensional list by appending/including multiple Lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have 3 Lists

```
a= [1,2,3]
b= [4,5,6]
c= []
```

Am trying to create

```
c = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I know `c.append(a)` followed by `c.append(b)` does the job. But is it possible to do it in a single line ?

Or any other method to "include" multiple list to one list so that we get a nDimensional list?

Or resort to `numpy` ?

**NOTE: Merging/Concatenating the lists using `zip` or `extend` or using "+" is not what am looking for**

Comment: Why don't you use the `extend` method this way: `c.extend([a, b])`? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @milanbalazs Ah yes!. All the extend method i tried was flattening the lists. This worked. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, I have added my solution as answer so you can accept it if it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extend` method to achieve what you want.

**Code:**

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = []

c.extend([a, b])

print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```